# SignedXml em NET 2 vs. NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, permissões, assinatura, file-permission

Tenho uma aplicação web em asp.net, que consome um webservice em delphi e que o mesmo utiliza uma DLL criada em C# para realizar assinaturas.

Com a aplicação web instalada no IIS, apresenta erro. Ao executar o webservice dentro do IIS utilizando o SOAPUI também apresenta erro. Ao testar o webservice fora do IIS usando o delphi + SOAPUI o processo funciona. Todos os testes foram realizados com a NET 4.5.

Todos os cenários com erro, ocorrem no método ComputeSignature(). Abaixo o erro reportado.

```
System.ArgumentException: Caracteres inválidos no caminho.
   em System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str, Boolean onlyCheckExtras)
   em System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   em System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   em System.AppDomainSetup.VerifyDir(String dir, Boolean normalize)
   em System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()
   em System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   em System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   em System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
   em System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
   em System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
   em System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
```

Na DLL ao trocar a versão do NET para a 2.0 método de assinatura funciona normalmente, usando dentro do IIS.

Gostaria de saber o motivo de funcionamento na 2.0 e se há alguma configuração que deve ser feita na DLL ou no IIS para funcionar na versão 4.5.

Segue abaixo o código da assinatura:

```
private XmlElement GerarAssinatura(bool IsSalvador, XmlDocument doc, XmlNode childNodes)
        {
            XmlElement retorno = null;
            try
            {
                Reference reference = new Reference();
                reference.Uri = "";

                XmlElement childElemen = (XmlElement)childNodes;
                if (childElemen.GetAttributeNode("Id") != null)
                {
                    reference.Uri = "#" + childElemen.GetAttributeNode("Id").Value;
                }
                else if (childElemen.GetAttributeNode("id") != null)
                {
                    reference.Uri = "#" + childElemen.GetAttributeNode("id").Value;
                }

                RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKeyProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificado.PrivateKey;

                SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
                signedXml.SigningKey = privateKeyProvider;

                XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                reference.AddTransform(env);

                if (!IsSalvador)
                {
                    XmlDsigC14NTransform c14 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
                    reference.AddTransform(c14);
                }

                signedXml.AddReference(reference);

                KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                KeyInfoX509Data x509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(certificado);
                if (IsSalvador)
                {
                    KeyInfoClause rsaKeyVal = new RSAKeyValue((RSA)privateKeyProvider);
                    keyInfo.AddClause(rsaKeyVal);

                    x509Data.AddSubjectName(certificado.SubjectName.Name.ToString());
                }

                keyInfo.AddClause(x509Data);

                signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

                signedXml.ComputeSignature();

                retorno = signedXml.GetXml();
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                AddMensagem("Ocorreu erro ao assinar. " + erro.InnerException.ToString());
            }
            return retorno;
        }
```